# How do i get the href of the next page in the navigation?

Tags: javascript, html

**Example:**

```
<ul id="nav1">
    <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

In this example im currently on Page 2, on Page 2 I want to place a `Next Page` button with an url to Page 3.

How do I get the `href` of Page 3 (with JavaScript)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use jQuery

```
$('.active').next('li').find('a').attr('href');  // page3.html
```

otherwise in plain javascript (example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gGRcX/2/ )

```
var ul   = document.getElementsById('nav1'),
    link = ul.querySelector('li.active + li a');

if (link) {   /* in case there's no "active" class 
               * (or if it's applied on last li element) 
               */
    console.log(link.href) // page3.html
}
```

`querySelectorAll` works on every modern browser and on IE8+

Comment: Does it say that he is using jQuery?

Comment: Would `$('.active').next('li').children().attr('href');` be quicker?

Comment: `children()` returns a list, right? Therefore it is not possible to use `attr()` on it. But then again, I dont know how god like jQuery is.

Comment: @Amberlamps it would return the `attr` of the first element returned by `children()`. Responsability to check that their method returns only 1 item is left to the dev, not handled by `attr()`

Comment: @F.Calderan: How can you be sure that the list is the first in the document?

Comment: @Amberlamps is just an example of how it can be achieved in plain javascript. Of course a good idea is to use an id for that list.

Comment: I got this function now:
function nextPage() {
  var ul = document.getElementById('nav1'),
  link = ul.querySelectorAll('li.active + li a')[0];

  alert(link.href);
 }
And this button:
<button onClick="nextPage">next</button>

But its still not working :(

Comment: @MaartenKuilman onclick="nextPage()" You're missing parens to execute the function (http://jsfiddle.net/yeTc8/)

Comment: You can use `ul.querySelector()`, it's the same as `ul.querySelectorAll()[0]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#nav1 .active + li > a').attr('href');
```

CSS3 FTW :)

Edit: might even be CSS 2.x, too lazy to check.

Comment: How is it related to CSS? This is just some Sizzle selectors.

Comment: Because Sizzle just parses string using the CSS specs ?